# Dynamic linqToEntity in c#

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

my code :

```
public List<Book> GetBook()
{
    var q = this.Entities.Book.Where("IdBook>1").ToList();
    return (q);
}
```

error :

> 'IdBook' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make
>   sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas
>   are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple
>   identifier, line 6, column 1.

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq doesn't allow using strings as expression unless you are using [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library (in such case the error says that `IdBook` doesn't exists). If you are not using Dynamic Linq library and you still have Where extension method accepting string it is a method expecting valid Entity SQL expression so try:

```
var q = this.Entities.Book.Where("it.IdBook > 1").ToList();
```